# Java: How to sort List of Lists by their size?

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have 9 different `ArrayList` and I want to have a list of the top 5.

I'm thinking of sorting those `ArrayLists` by their sizes.

Is it possible to do that?  If so, how can I achieve that?

---

After a few try i finally got it working, just want to share it with everyone.

it will be better to get the size of the arraylist and add it to the big arraylist

```
// creates an ArrayList that holds ArrayLists 
List allTheLists = new ArrayList(); 
allTheLists.add(pbaustraliaList.size());
allTheLists.add(pbotherList.size()); 
allTheLists.add(pbunitedStatesList.size()); 
allTheLists.add(pbunitedKingdomList.size()); 
allTheLists.add(pbchinaList.size()); 
allTheLists.add(pbgermanyList.size()); 
allTheLists.add(pbindiaList.size()); 
allTheLists.add(pbjapanList.size()); 
allTheLists.add(pbsingaporeList.size()); 
Comparator comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();
Collections.sort(allTheLists,comparator);

//display elements of ArrayList    
System.out.println("ArrayList elements after sorting in descending order : ");    
for(int i=0; i<allTheLists.size(); i++) {     
    System.out.println(allTheLists.get(i));   
}
```

Comment: You want to have, for example, the shortest list first and the longest last?

Comment: the longest first. just saw an example from justin. i shall try that first. thanks guys =)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What you could do is the following:

```
// this List of lists will need to contain 
// all of the ArrayLists you would like to sort
List<ArrayList> allTheLists; 
Collections.sort(allTheLists, new Comparator<ArrayList>(){
    public int compare(ArrayList a1, ArrayList a2) {
        return a2.size() - a1.size(); // assumes you want biggest to smallest
    }
});
```

This will sort the list of lists by the length of each list.  The first element in the sorted list will be the longest list, and the last one will be the shortest list.

Then, you can iterate through the first 5 lists to see what the top 5 were.

**Some links for reference:**

- [Sorting tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html)
- [Collections Javadoc](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)
- [Comparator Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html)

---

Depending on how you have your `ArrayLists` stored, the code to create a `List<ArrayList>` would look something like this:

```
// creates an ArrayList that holds ArrayLists
List<ArrayList> allTheLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
allTheLists.add(yourList1);
allTheLists.add(yourList2);
...
allTheLists.add(yourList9);
```

Comment: +1, but I would use List instead of ArrayList as type parameter.

Comment: @pcjuzer, thanks.  I would too.  But this is tailored to the needs of the question.

Comment: Changing all instances of `ArrayList` to `List<?>` works just as well in this specific case, yet also is more extensible and avoids raw type warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` method that's available on a List needs a `Comparator`. That comparator can be created with the `Comparator.comparing` method, with additional special implementations including for extracting and comparing an int - `Comparator.comparingInt`.

```
import static java.util.Comparator.comparingInt;
...
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = ...
listOfLists.sort(comparingInt(List::size));
```

`List::size` will map a `List` to an int (the size of the list) and use that to create a new `Comparator` that can be used for our sorting purposes.

If you want largest first

```
listOfLists.sort(comparingInt(List::size).reversed());
```

Dump the top 5 (switching over to Java 8 streams):

```
listOfLists.stream()
  .sorted(comparingInt(List::size).reversed())
  .limit(5)
  .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this as well

```
public static <T> List<List<T>> sort(List<List<T>> list) {
        list.sort((xs1, xs2) -> xs1.size() - xs2.size());
        return list;
    }
```